# AsyncTask in Android with return interface

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-studio-2.1

I'm using an AsyncTask in android to do a request to a server and then recive the data to another class. I know that AsyncTask don't return anything so I used code made by other people to return strings using an interface.

Here you have the AsyncTask class code:

```
public class WebRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

//Data
public String mFileContents = "false";

//API-Info
public WebRequestResponse delegate = null;

public WebRequest(WebRequestResponse asyncResponse) {
    delegate = asyncResponse;//Assigning call back interfacethrough constructor
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    mFileContents = downloadFile(params[0]);
    if(mFileContents == null) {
        Log.d("DownloadData", "Error Downloading");
    }
    return mFileContents;
}

protected void oonPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    delegate.processFinish(mFileContents);
    Log.d("DownloadData", "Result was: " + result); //result
}

private String downloadFile(String urlPath) {
    StringBuilder tempBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlPath);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int response = connection.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("DownloadData", "The response code was " + response);
        InputStream is  = connection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

        int charRead;
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[500];
        while(true){
            charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer);
            if(charRead <=0) {
                break;
            }
            tempBuffer.append(String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead));
        }

        return tempBuffer.toString();

    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.d("DownloadData", "IO Exception reading data: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(SecurityException e) {
        Log.d("DownloadData", "Security exception. Needs permissions? " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Now, the Interface:

```
public interface WebRequestResponse {
void processFinish(String output);
}
```

In the sync class I have this:

```
public class API implements WebRequestResponse {
```

And I make the execute like:

```
    public static void StartRequest(String url) {
    String response = null;
    WebRequest Request = new WebRequest(new WebRequestResponse() {

        @Override
        public void processFinish(String output) {
            Test(output); //Testing the response code
        }
    });
    Request.execute(url);
}
```

The problem is that the code never is called and never return anything. Using Log.d I found that nothing works from here: "delegate.processFinish(mFileContents);" that is allocated in the AsyncTask class. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to write `protected void oonPostExecute(String result)` with double "oo"?

Comment: Lol.... Thanks xDDD

Comment: :) Glad I could help! Note that it's a good practice to add annotation @override so that this kind of errors never happen...

Comment: Using the Volley library would mean you would have to write less code :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Rucsi, I he found that I was writting onPostExecute with double o